# Multiple page HTML not rendering properly in HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp

Tags: c#, rendering

I have created a sample application in which i have used nuget package HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp

I used the below code in my console application to generate pdf from html:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText("..//..//HTML//dfdf.html");
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
document.Info.Title = "Test";

PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

//XPdfFontOptions options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

// Create a font
TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerateConfig pdfconfg = new TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerateConfig();
pdfconfg.PageSize = PdfSharp.PageSize.A4;
document = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(input, pdfconfg);

document.Save("..//..//PDF//dfdf.pdf");
```

But when the text of html page is very long then it is not rending the content. Only blank pages are generating. Please help. I want to use this library as it provide desired output.

Comment: If you think there is a bug in the HtmlRenderer then maybe submit your file to the developers. Or download the source of HtmlRenderer, step through it in a debugger and look what goes on. Half of the lines in your code snippet are red herrings, the rest looks OK - and without the file dfdf.html the problem cannot be replicated.

Comment: dfdf.html is just a sample file. You can take any long html file which can generate approximately more than 1 page of pdf. This will replicate the issue.